# Keep track of changes made for the purpose of debugging in C#/Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, change-tracking

Im working on a project where I have to change certain values of variables for debugging. In the release-version there are long TimeSpans between some actions. For debugging I would change the values of the TimeSpans in order to not having to wait so long. Example:

```
//For Release:
//TimeSpan intervall1 = new TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90);

//For Debug:
TimeSpan intervall1 = new TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

I have many such cases, so it's easy to forget to undo the changes for the release.

Is there a way to keep track of changes like these? Or are there better ways for debugging in such cases?

Comment: you should be using application settings for this and have a configuration file for each environment https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2019

Comment: everyone so far has been pretty much spot on that you should use a config file but a potentially simpler option is using compiler directives. I'm not putting this as an answer as it really isn't the best option but it is the simplest option for the basic requirements

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is using [`#if preprocessor directive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) to check if in Debug mode.

Here is the demo.

```
#if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine("Mode=Debug");
            TimeSpan intervall1 = new TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
#else
            Console.WriteLine("Mode=Release"); 
            TimeSpan intervall1 = new TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, those sorts of values would be provided by some external configuration that could vary, either by being passed to the method in question, or by being read from, say, a configuration file that varies by environment, so you when you're running your tests, the file `/config/test.json` is loaded, but in production the file `/config/prod.json` is loaded.

Because life is too short to do it the hard way.

Comment: Could you give me some hints on how to achieve this? What would you write in these config files? Would you read the file using a method like File.ReadAllText(test.json), then parse the content and assign it to the field?

Comment: @Patb: A common pattern is to have, say, a `config` directory with a config file for each runtime environment — say `dev.yaml`, `test.yaml`, `production.yaml`. An environment variable is set (or a command line flag) to indicate the runtime environment. When your app launches, it looks at the environment variable or command line flag and uses that to decide what configuration to load and make available to the app. Now you can change configuration data (like a timeout setting) without needing to change and recompile code. Or to need to remember to change it back.